# why i am getting "ValueError: output array is read-only"

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

sns.histplot(x=col, hue='stroke', data=df, kde=True, ax=ax, bins=30)"
in this line i am getting the error.
"ValueError: output array is read-only"

```
# Numerical columns to visualize
numerical_columns = ['age', 'avg_glucose_level', 'bmi']
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(numerical_columns), ncols=1, figsize=(10, 5 * len(numerical_columns)))
# Plot histograms for each numerical column
for col, ax in zip(numerical_columns, axes):
    sns.histplot(x=col, hue='stroke', data=df, kde=True, ax=ax, bins=30)
    ax.set_title(f'Histogram of {col} vs Stroke')
    ax.set_xlabel(col)
    ax.set_ylabel('Count')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

i was trying to draw a histogram for my numeric features with kde true.`

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.  What is ```sns```?

Comment: There are operations that make read only arrays, but you don't give us enough information to say which.